# Trying to install Python 3 package RPi.GPIO

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am having difficulty installing the RPi.GPIO package for Python 3 on Raspberry Pi. I am getting this error:

> python3-rpi.gpio is not available, but is referred to by another package. This might mean that the package is missing, has been obsolete, or is only available from another source

This error occurs when I enter the command `sudo apt-get -y install python3-rpi.gpio`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: `pip install RPi.GPIO` may solve it

Answer (score 2):

You may install it with pip :

```
pip install RPi.GPIO
```

Comment: Either with `sudo` or `--user`.